# Proving that $\operatorname{cl} G=\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus\operatorname{cl} G))$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that if $G$ is an open set in $(X,\tau)$ then $\overline{G}=\overline{X\setminus\overline{X\setminus\overline{G}}}$

My Attempt

Note that

$\overline{X\setminus\overline{X\setminus\overline{G}}}$=
$ \overline{X\setminus{X\setminus{G^0}}}=\overline{G^0}=\overline{G}$

Can someone verify if this is correct and also can you share some better solution.
Even if this solution is good, can you share some alternate solution.
I am feeling guilty of remembering some non-trivial results

Comment: Show your steps.